# CSS for table gets affected with Table in Date Picker

Tags: css, css-tables

I am trying to create a CSS to display a table to show all contents in iPad

in order to avoid displaying horizontally. The Problem I am facing here is

in Date    Picker table, which gets affected with this CSS .

```
    @media 
      only screen and (max-width: 760px),
      (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

         /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */

        table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
            display: block; 
        }


         /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */

        thead tr { 
            position: absolute;
            top: -9999px;
            left: -9999px;
        }

        tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

        td { 
            /* Behave  like a "row" */
            border: none;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
            position: relative;
            padding-left: 50%; 
        }

        td:before { 

            /* Now like a table header */

            position: absolute;
            /* Top/left values mimic padding */
            top: 6px;
            left: 6px;
            width: 45%; 
            padding-right: 10px; 
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
     }
```

How can I avoid the Date Picker table to get affected with this CSS

Comment: Add a class to your table and target it specifically.

Comment: I would specify this CSS as a certain class. For example .className td { ... }

Comment: @SalmanA table.className , thead, tbody, th, td, tr { 
            display: block; 
        }

Comment: A little more actually: `table.className, table.className thead, table.className tbody /*, ...*/ { display: block; }` etc.